# Grammar about Comparison

Tags: grammar

When we say,"No other mountain is higher than Mt. Everest", I have a question, why should I use "No other + a singular noun..."

"No other" means "Not any other"?

Comment: Try to avoid placeholders like "X", especially when there is real word that could be used instead. I've edited.

Comment: What do you mean by *should*? Both versions are possible; it's just a matter of style and personal choice. Are you really asking what prompts people to use one phrase over the other—or are you actually unsure if "no other" means "not any other"? (You seem to have asked two different questions.)

Answer (score 1):

"No" functions a determiner, similar to word like "The" or "Your". There may be several determiners in front of a noun, forming a short phrase.

Here we have "no other" forming a determinative phrase in front of the noun "mountain". The sentence quoted is correct English.